# Reducir espacio de programa en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy usando **C++** con **Sockets** y uso *winsock* para ello, pero veo que mi archivo final es muy pesado para lo poco que hace (+1MB) compilo con *G++* con argumento _-lws2_32 -static -static-libstdc++_ como puedo reducir el espacio?

Comment: Al parecer añadir bibliotecas externas como "winsock" produce que también se agreguen al archivo compilado. Puedes comprobar esto creando una aplicación vacía sin añadir ninguna biblioteca, luego añadir una y comparar los tamaños?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veo que estas usando **enlazado estático** `-static` `-static-libstdc++`.

Eso fuerza a incluir en tu archivo *todo el código* **que uses** de las bibliotecas que utilices, lo cual aumentará su tamaño considerablemente.

No indicas *exactamente* que estas haciendo, así que te ofrezco varias soluciones genéricas, que puedes combinar entre si:

#### 1- Utiliza enlazado dinámico

Esto hará que el código de las bibliotecas no sea incluido en tu archivo, sino que será *enlazado* con tu aplicación en tiempo de ejecución.

Para ello, elimina `-static` y `-static-libstdc++`.

En caso de necesidad, puedes indicar *exactamente* que bibliotecas enlazar estáticas y cuales dinámicas mediante la combinación de `-static` y `-shared`.

#### 2- Comprimir el archivo resultante

Existen compresores diseñados para auto-descomprimir el código al ejecutarse; **no** son simples `zip`, sino que se encargan de toda la gestión de memoria necesaria, tanto para ejecutables como para bibliotecas.

Esto hará que *el archivo* se auto-descomprima en memória al ejecutarlo; su tamaño en memoria seguirá siendo el mismo (o un poco mayor, debido al propio código de descompresión), pero el tamaño físico del archivo disminuirá.

Página principal de uno de ellos: [`upx`](https://upx.github.io/).

#### 3- Elimina caracteristicas de C++ *que no uses* en tu proyecto

Tales como el soporte RTTI y las excepciones, mediante las opciones `-fno-rtti` y/o `fno-exceptions`.

Esto *no siempre funcionará*; si tu código utiliza alguna de estas características, el compilador seguirá generando el código necesario.

De entrada, necesitaras crearte tu propio `operator new( )`, ya que el estandar dicta que emita excepciones ante fallos en la reserva de memoria.

#### 4- Utiliza bibliotecas alternativas

Si necesitas el enlazado estático por algún motivo, existen librerías alternativas, especialmente pensadas para su enlazado estático, con soporte en mayor o menor grado de los estandares C y C++, tales como [uClibc](https://uclibc.org/) o [uClibc++](https://cxx.uclibc.org/).

Su uso, en combinación con ciertas opciones del G++ como `-nostdlib`, `-nodefaultlibs`, `-nostartfiles`, e incluso `-freestanding`, te permitirá mantener tu archivo generado reducido en tamaño, pero grande en funcionalidad; a cambio, tal vez tengas que codificar por tu cuenta ciertas cosas que *no estén soportadas* por la biblioteca escogida.

### Conclusión

Con imaginación y *muchas líneas de código*, puedes reducir **mucho** el tamaño del ejecutable; por ejemplo, haz clases propias que realicen llamadas a funciones de la librería C, sin utilizar para nada la `libstdc++`, lo compilas estático utilizando `-freestanding` y enlazándolo con `uClibc`, y luego comprimes el archivo final resultante.

El *lifting* obtenido puede ser asombroso.

**EDITO**

¿ Sabeis lo de `si eschucas cascos, busca caballos y no cebras` ? pues yo tengo tendencia a buscar *unicornios*.

Lo mas fácil es asegurarnos de **no incluir** ninguna de las opciones que generan información de depuración, tales como `-g`, `-ggdb`.

También podemos comenzar por *optimizar* el código generado, usando las opciones `-O` del G++:

`-O0`      -> **Sin** ninguna optimización.
`-O`, `-O1` -> Optimización *ligera*.
`-O2`       -> Optimización mas fuerte que `-O1`. Es la recomendada.
`-O3`       -> Optimización *agresiva*. Ojo con ella, *puede* romper cosas si trabajamos a bajo nivel (marcos de pila, prólogo de funciones, ... ).
`-Os`       -> Similar a `-O2`, pero orientada a *reducir el tamaño* del archivo generado.
`-Ofast`    -> Similar a `-O3`, pero orientada a *aumentar la velocidad* de ejecución.
`-Og`       -> Optimizaciones que *no interfieran* con la depuración.

La [documentación de `g++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), como siempre, es un buen punto en el que comenzar.

**EDITO 2**

Lo que dije antes de los cascos y los caballos ;-)

#### 4- Consideraciones para C++

Usa la opción `-fno-inline` de G++; esto forzará el uso de las funciones `inline` como si fueran *normales*, mediante llamadas.

Limita el uso de las `template< >`. En última instancia, estarás colocando copias de cada plantilla para cada conjunto de parámetros que uses.

Esto no es *literalmente cierto*; las `template< >` se suelen diseñar como un agregado de otras `template< >`, cada una especializada en un determinado aspecto. Además, suelen incluir un *núcleo* lo más general posible, precisamente para limitar esa duplicación de código.

**Excepciones a lo anterior**

Si usas `template< >` con tipos básicos como parámetros (`int`, `char`, `void *`, y en general, tipos *POD*), el código generado *no será mayor*; el compilador se encargará de la *magia*.

Si solo usas 1 instancia de una `template< >`, *tampoco* penalizas el tamaño. No puedes utilizar menos de 1 copia del código de la plantilla.

**EDITO 3**

Como amablemente me indica @eferion en sus comentarios, hay un punto no comentado:

Mediante el enlazado dinámico, *arrastramos* las bibliotecas que usemos; es decir, si nuestra aplicación se enlaza con, por ejemplo, `libChachiPiruli`, nuestra aplicación **no arrancará** si dicha biblioteca no está disponible en el sistema; será necesario *copiarla* (instalarla) en cualquier equipo en el que se intente ejecutar nuestra aplicación.

Mediante el enlazado estático, esto no ocurre. El código *realmente utilizado* de la `libChachiPiruli` será *insertado* en nuestro propio ejecutable, sin depender de nada más. **No** será necesario *copiar* ni instalar nada en el equipo en el que intentemos ejecutar nuestra aplicación.

De lo anterior, extraemos lo siguiente:

El tamaño de `nuestro codigo` + `bibliotecas requeridas` es **mayor** si usamos enlace dinámico que si utilizamos enlace estático. En el primer caso, se necesita *toda* la biblioteca; en el segundo, ya tenemos incorporado todo el código, y no necesitamos mas.

Dejamos el tema de la bibliotecas. Consideraciones sobre su uso de memoria, ventajas, e inconvenientes, da para *otra* respuesta, y entra de lleno en temas de gestión de memoria, carga de aplicaciones, y otras *malas yerbas*.

Comment: Se te olvidó comentar que el enlazado dinámico implica que has de llevar las librerías en archivos independientes para que el programa funcione... Eso no veo que sea necesariamente una mejora

Comment: El autor pregunta sobre su *archivo final*, no sobre el *total de archivos*; en todo caso, tienes razón, la suma final `codigo propio` + `bibliotecas` es mayor si enlazas dinámico; con enlazado estático, solo incluyes lo que uses, con el dinámico, *arrastras* la biblioteca. Buena puntualización :-)

Comment: Ya bueno, pero es algo que creo que deberías indicar ya que el que pregunta esto seguramente desconozca ese efecto secundario... Y es muy frustrante tener un ejecutable que funciona y ver que en otra máquina ni arranca

Comment: Por lo demás poco que añadir. Es una respuesta bastante detallada

Comment: Gracias. Sigo tu recomendación y edito (y van 3) xD